# How to add additional service for already registered component

Tags: castle-windsor

I have problem adding additional service for already registered component.
I have the following situation:

```
public class MyImplementation : BaseClass, IInterface
{

}
```

Somewhere in the infrastructure of my application (which is not subject to change), my class is registered in the following manner:

```
container.Register(Classes
                               .FromThisAssembly()
                               .BasedOn(typeof (BaseClass))
                               .WithServiceBase()                                                                      
                               .LifestyleTransient());
```

What I want to do now, is to add additional service to MyImplementation component. I tried do it in my installer with the following method:

```
container.Register(Classes
                               .FromThisAssembly()
                               .BasedOn(typeof (IInterface))
                               .WithServiceBase()                                                                      
                               .LifestyleTransient());
```

But when trying to resolve IInterface from container I get error saying there is no component registered for IInterface.

My question is, if it is possible to add additional service to already registered component?
Thanks in advance.
Mike

Comment: it's possible to register multiple services using `AllInterfaces()` - however, in your case this would probably mean changing the existing registration. see allinterfaces docs here: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx

Comment: This was my initial solution. However this will potentially register components with interfaces that I do not want, which does not seems nice to me :/ However I still did not come up with better solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you change second registration it will work:

```
container.Register(Classes
                           .FromThisAssembly()
                           .BasedOn(typeof (IInterface))
                           .WithServiceAllInterfaces()                                                                      
                           .LifestyleTransient());
```